# Num of actor instance

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I'm new to akka-actor and confused with some problems:

1. when I create an actorSystem, and use actorOf(Props(classOf[AX], ...)) to create actor in main method, how many instances are there for my actor AX?
2. If the answer to Q1 was just one, does this mean whatever data-structure I created in the AX actor class's definition will only appear in one thread and I should not concern about concurrency problems?
3. What if one of my actor's action (one case in receive method) is a time consuming task and would take quite long time to finish? Will my single Actor instance not responding until it finish that task?
4. If the answer to Q3 is right, what I am supposed to do to prevent my actor from not responding? Should I start another thread and send another message back to it until finish the task? Is there a best practice there I should follow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. yes, the actor system will only create 1 actor instance for each time you call the 'actorOf' method. However, when using a Router it is possible to create 1 router which spreads the load to any number of actors. So in that case it is possible to construct multiple instances, but 'normally' using actorOf just creates 1 instance.
2. Yes, within an actor you do not have to worry about concurrency because Akka guarantees that any actor only processes 1 message at the time. You must take care not to somehow mutate the state of the actor from code outside the actor. So whenever exposing the actor state, always do this using an immutable class. Case classes are excellent for this. But also be ware of modifying the actor state when completing a Future from inside the actor. Since the Future runs on it's own thread you could have a concurrency issue when the Future completes and the actor is processing a next message at the same time.
   The actor executes on 1 thread at the time, but this might be a different thread each time the actor executes.
3. Akka is a highly concurrent and distributed framework, everything is asynchronous and non-blocking and you must do the same within your application. Scala and Akka provide several solutions to do this. Whenever you have a time consuming task within an actor you might either delegate the time consuming task to another actor just for this purpose, use Futures or use Scala's 'async/await/blocking'. When using 'blocking' you give a hint to the compiler/runtime a blocking action is done and the runtime might start additional thread to prevent thread starvation. The [Scala Concurrent programming book](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/learning-concurrent-programming-scala) is an excellent guide to learn this stuff. Also look at the [concurrent package ScalaDocs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.concurrent.package) and [Neophyte's Guide to Scala](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/16/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-9-promises-and-futures-in-practice.html).
   If the actor really has to wait for the time consuming task to complete, then yes, your actor can only respond when that's finished. But this is a very 'request-response' way of thinking. Try to get away from this. The actor could also respond immediately indicating the task has started and send an additional message once the task has been completed.
   With time consuming tasks always be sure to use a different threadpool so the ActorSystem will not be blocked because all of it's available threads are used up by time consuming tasks. For Future's you can provide a separate ExecutionContext (do not use the ActorSystem's Dispatch context for this!), but via Akka's configuration you can also configure certain actors to run on a different thread pool.
4. See 3.

Success!

Answer (score 1):

1. one instance (if you declare a router in your props then (maybe) more than one)
2. Yes. This is one of the advantages of actors.
3. Yes. An Actor will process messages sequentially.
4. You can use scala.concurrent.Future (do not use actor state in the future) or delegate the work to a child actor (the main actor can manage the state and can respond to messages). Future or child-actor depends on use case.